# Are Google Tink ciphertexts portable across programming languages?

Tags: tink

I am wondering if I encrypt a plaintext, let's say using the Go SDK whether I will be able to decrypt it using the Java SDK? Is that a design goal of the library to guarantee this portability across programming languages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work. Cross-language compatibility is a design goal. We have tests to detect any incompatibility issues, but if you found any please file a bug on https://github.com/google/tink.